# What are the rules for a space marine commander?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I was searching the space marines section at a local warhammer shop when I saw a miniature called the space marine commander, I looked for it in my index but his rules weren't in it. What are the rules for a space marine commander? Do they follow the same rules as the captain? Please let me know so I can decide whether to get him or not.

Answer (score 1):

Was this [Space Marine Commander](https://www.games-workshop.com/en-US/Space-Marine-Commander-2015) the miniature you saw?

If so, at least according to the description on the website, it appears you'd be treating this as a Captain for rules purposes:

> Space Marine Commander
>
> A Captain leads each of the ten Companies of a Space Marine Chapter. They are second in experience only to the Chapter Master and each is a warrior so deadly that he will rarely meet his match. Each Captain is an inspirational and determined leader, able to coordinate the Space Marines under his command whatever the opposition.